# 720p Option Missing in the Quality Settings, PotPlayer

Tags: video-playback, daum-pot-player

As the title says, the 720 Option at the top of the Quality Settings in PotPlayer is gone and because of it, YouTube videos load slowly and the progress bar is also slow. Is it because of PotPlayer or my Wifi? How do I fix? Also the video codec is AVC1 and I have already tried changing settings, restarting my computer, changing WiFis , resetting preferences, etc.

Comment: I'd be surprised if many people here use PotPlayer. I think most use VLC https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.nl.html